# In $\int f d \mu_1 = \mu_2 (\{(x,y) \in D \times V )| 0\leq y \leq f(x)\}), f: D\rightarrow V, f\geq 0$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I just read about the Lebesgue-Integral and wondered, why they defined it by taking advantage of these sequences of functions What we want is something like the space enclosed by the graph of the function and the Domain crossed 0, don't we?
$$\int f d \mu_1 = \mu_2 (\{(x,y) \in D \times V )| 0\leq y \leq f(x)\}), f: D\rightarrow V, f\geq 0$$

$\mu_1$ is the Lebesgue Measure in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\Sigma_1, \mu_1)$, $\mu_2$ the Lebesgue-Measure in $(\mathbb{R}^{n+k},\Sigma_2,\mu_2), D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}, V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k}$. So this only works if $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$for a $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I am pretty sure this is true, but why?

Comment: if $\mu$ is the measure on $D$ and $\lambda$ the measure on $V$ the product measure on $D\times V$ should be written $\mu\times\lambda$.

Comment: Our analysis prof liked this way, and actually did define Lebesgue integral as the measure of the area below the graph of the function, with $V=\Bbb R$. First,  for nonnegative functions, then linearity extends it to real then complex valued functions..

Comment: @PeterMelech I precised the question

Comment: Does it have something to do with Fubini?

Comment: Normally $\mu_n$ is defined by means of $\mu_k$ where $k<n$. That works because $1,2,3,\dots$ is a well-ordening (you must start somewhere, right?). It seems you want to turn things around. But then we come into trouble with defining because $\dots,3,2,1$ is not a well-ordening. Where to start? BTW, I tend to look at measures as functions on functions instead of seeing them as functions on sets.

Comment: @drhab I have not defined a $\mu_n$. Is it clear now with the edit?